# Google Analytics - Embed API - Getting an OAuth Error

Tags: google-api, google-apps

I am trying to follow the example [here](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/basic-dashboard/) to embed some Google Analytics statistics in my web app.

My HTML looks as follows:

```
<div class="page-header">
    <h3 class="text-center">WAND Sessions</h3>
</div>

<br/>
<br/>

<div id="embed-api-auth-container"></div>
<div id="chart-container"></div>
<div id="view-selector-container"></div>

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        (function(w, d, s, g, js, fs) {
            g = w.gapi || (w.gapi = {});
            g.analytics = { q: [], ready: function(f) { this.q.push(f); } };
            js = d.createElement(s);
            fs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            js.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
            fs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fs);
            js.onload = function() { g.load('analytics'); };
        }(window, document, 'script'));
    </script>

    <script src="~/Scripts/GoogleAnalytics/viewSessions.js"></script>
}
```

My viewSessions.js file looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    gapi.analytics.ready(function () {

        /**
         * Authorize the user immediately if the user has already granted access.
         * If no access has been created, render an authorize button inside the
         * element with the ID "embed-api-auth-container".
         */
        gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
            container: 'embed-api-auth-container',
            clientid: 'xxxxxxxxx'
        });

        /**
         * Create a new ViewSelector instance to be rendered inside of an
         * element with the id "view-selector-container".
         */
        var viewSelector = new gapi.analytics.ViewSelector({
            container: 'view-selector-container'
        });

        // Render the view selector to the page.
        viewSelector.execute();


        /**
         * Create a new DataChart instance with the given query parameters
         * and Google chart options. It will be rendered inside an element
         * with the id "chart-container".
         */
        var dataChart = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
            query: {
                metrics: 'ga:sessions',
                dimensions: 'ga:date',
                'start-date': '30daysAgo',
                'end-date': 'yesterday'
            },
            chart: {
                container: 'chart-container',
                type: 'LINE',
                options: {
                    width: '100%'
                }
            }
        });


        /**
         * Render the dataChart on the page whenever a new view is selected.
         */
        viewSelector.on('change', function (ids) {
            dataChart.set({ query: { ids: ids } }).execute();
        });

    });
});
```

When I load my page, all I see is this:

[image]

If I click on this, I get a Google error dialog saying

```
401 Error: invalid_client

The OAuth client was not found.
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/getting-started check creating client id make sure you did it corectly

Comment: @DaImTo - That was the problem. My client Id was not correct. If you create this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation on that page is not very good. I have mentioned this to Google in the past.

You need to go to Google Developers console and create your own client id using an OAuth credentials.

The [Google Analytics Embeded API getting started](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/getting-started) page tells you how to do that.

> Create a New Client ID
>
> The Embed API handles almost all of the authorization process for you
>   by providing a one-click sign-in component that uses the familiar
>   OAuth 2.0 flow. In order to get this button working on your page
>   you'll need a client ID.
>
> If you've never created a client ID, you can do so by following  these
>   instructions.
>
> As you go through the instructions, it's important that you not
>   overlook these two critical steps: • Enable the Analytics API 
>  • Set the
>   correct origins
>
> The origins control what domains are allowed to use this code to
>   authorize users. This prevents other people from copying your code and
>   running it on their site.
>
> For example, if your website is hosted on the domain example.com, make
>   sure to set the following origin for your client ID
>   http://example.com. If you want to test your code locally, you'll need
>   to add the origin for your local server as well, for example:
>   http://localhost:8080.